# I am trying to mix pivot table values in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have three table category and products with its pivot table as category_product

One category has many products

I want the category name in attributes of products with its own field.

```
    $saijal = "Our Products";
    $products = Product::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('categories')->get();

    $abc = new Collection();
    foreach($products as $pro)
    {
        $abc->put($pro->id,$pro);
    }

    foreach($products as $k => $pro)
    {
        $abc->get($pro->id)->children = new Collection();
        $abc->get($pro->id)->categoryName= $pro->categories->name;

        $abc->get($pro->id)->children->push($pro);
        unset($pro[$k]);

    }
    dd($abc);
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: 'category_name' ? there are many categories for products.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to access an attribute called "categoryName" directly from the product object. In order to do this, simply set up an attribute getter in the Product.php model that looks like this:

```
public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->category->name;
}
```

Then you can simply reference the category name like this:

```
$product->categoryName
```

The main issue I see is that you are referring to "categories" in your code as if it is plural. If the product belongs to many categories, the solution would be different and your relationships would require a pivot table, as you describe. But if the product just belongs to one category, as your code implies, the solution above should be sufficient and you actually do not need a pivot table. You would just have a category_id column directly in the products table.

If you do want to have multiple categories for each product, you could do something similar but return an array:

```
public function getCategoryNamesAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories->pluck('name');
}
```

This would return an array of category names associated with this Product, and would be accessible as:

```
$product->categoryNames
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom attributes to `appends` array **(not `attributes` array)**.

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['category_names'];

    public function getCategoryNamesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->categories->map->name;
    }
}
```

you can access this attribute as,

```
$product->category_names;
```

**Note**

The benefit of adding this to the `appends` array is. If you don't add this to the appends array, When you call `toArray()` or `toJson()` or send this `$product` via json. you loses this attribute.